# Чем отличается InvokeMember("click") от RaiseEvent("click");

Tags: c#

В чем отличие этих 2-ух методов класса `HtmlElement`?
`InvokeMember("click")` и `RaiseEvent("click");`
И какие действия кроме `"click"` можно им отправлять?

Comment: А о каком классе идёт речь?

Comment: Речь идет об HtmlElement

Comment: Может вы имели ввиду `RaiseEvent("click");`?

Comment: Именно, это очепятка

Answer (score 1):

Так вот, из MSDN:

### InvokeMember(String):

> Выполняет невыявленный метод в базовом элементе DOM данного элемента.
>   String - Имя вызываемого свойства или метода.

### RaiseEvent(String):

> Приводит к тому, что именованное событие вызывает все зарегистрированные обработчики событий.
>   String - Имя создаваемого события.

Можете полностью прочитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx):

Comment: Это и я нашел, я хотел, что бы мне объяснили суть, может с примером.